# Toolbar button in UIDatePicker shows only after double click on TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I wanna let user to set time in `UIDatePicker` which shows after click on `UITextField`, but Toolbar with done button shows only when user will click twice on `UITextField`.

```
func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date
        datepickerView.datePickerMode = .time

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));

        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        workHoursStartTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    }

@objc func doneButtonDatePicker(){

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        workHoursStartTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datepickerView.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

@objc func tapOnStartWork(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Start work")
        datepickerView.isHidden = false
        showDatePicker()

    }
```

and calling method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapStartWork = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnStartWork(gestureReconizer:)))
        workHoursStartTextField.addGestureRecognizer(tapStartWork)
}
```

When I click on `UITextField` text "Start work" prints in console, but toolbar button is still hide.

Comment: try self.view.datepickerView.isHidden = false its probably because of view it's on the which view ?

Comment: self.view.layoutIfNeeded()  and use this

Comment: @İsaGİRİŞKEN where I should use self.view.layoutIfNeeded() ? In which place? datePicker.isHidden = false was on the basic view. I added self, but it didn't change anything

Comment: try in super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: @İsaGİRİŞKEN Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: Textfield have its on tap gesture, you need to set is editable false to make action against your custom gesture.